# Facebook Friend Request Android with Swiper.js (Swipe Centered)

Tags: facebook, mobile, swiper.js

I'm trying to implement this Facebook Friend Request like page using swiper.js (http://www.idangero.us/swiper/demos/07-centered.html) But I'm getting no results.

Could anybody help me with this?

This is what I want:
[image]

This is what I get: lol
[image]